# There is only one comonoid object in Set

Tags: category-theory

Let $(X, \eta : X\longrightarrow i, \mu : X\longrightarrow X\sqcup X)$ be an monoid object in Set. Because $i$ is intitial, $i = \emptyset$. But there is only one map $X\longrightarrow\emptyset$ and only if $X = \emptyset$, namely $\eta = \emptyset$.It follows $(X, \eta, \mu) = (\emptyset,\emptyset , \emptyset)$. Is it correct?

Comment: It is correct if you mean "a comonoid object with respect to the monoidal structure on Set given by the coproduct". You can also have comonoid objects with respect to the cartesian product (or other monoidal structures).